# How do I install a .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 6.0?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dotnet-sdk

I am trying to compile a Visual Studio project (`.sln`) and get the error message
*Error  NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 6.0.  Either target .NET Core 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 6.0.*

Now, I wonder how or where I can install .NET Core 6.0.

I have found https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet but it only has a .NET Core 3.1.

So, I'd appreciate any pointer towards finding .NET Core 6.0.

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0

Comment: So, *.NET 6.0* is the same as *.NET Core 6.0*?

Comment: Yes, with.NET 5.0 the name changed.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/

Answer (score 4):

Beware of the following caveat.

VS 16.11 and lower will no longer load with .NET SDK 6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/vs-msbuild-version

Comment: Since I cannot update to VS 2022 for various reasons, this info save my life